# Transmission-daemon - dangling symlink and dpkg error

Tags: server, transmission

After some attempts to install Transmission I couldnt get the webUI working. This made me want to make a fresh start by removing all my transmission files. I encounter the following on my Ubuntu 14.10 Server.

```
chris@homeserver:~$ sudo apt-get remove transmission-daemon                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libnatpmp1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  transmission-daemon
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 606 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 142422 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing transmission-daemon (2.84-0ubuntu0.14.10.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: dangling symlink: /etc/rc2.d/S01transmission-daemon
dpkg: error processing package transmission-daemon (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 102
invoke-rc.d: dangling symlink: /etc/rc2.d/S01transmission-daemon
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 102
Errors were encountered while processing:
 transmission-daemon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The same error keeps popping up even if I want to reinstall of force install transmission-daemon.

My knowledge of Ubuntu and Linux is very limited I am a beginner. Can someone explain what is going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably some previous version of the package was broken. I'd suggest deleting the file...

`sudo rm /etc/rc2.d/S01transmission-daemon`